# Selecting only matching mask between 2 FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, extract-by-mask, map-matching

In order to do linear regression between Landsat8 and Modis Aqua datasets I want to select the images of Landsat & Modis that cover each other for each date.
I have already selected the matching date images.
I tried to implement this function :

```
function maskInRoi(img){
  return img.set({
    "mask": img.rename("mask").mask().reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry:ROI,
      crs:ModisProjection
    }).get("mask") 
  })
}
```

But Instead of ROI it would be the mask of the other dataset.
So I want to transform the mask of the image of the first dataset to  use the maskInROI function with this geometry
Do anybody can help me with this ?

Here is a full version of my code :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f7da4463739bc7375ee7f355b56f0048